# Trying to integrate highlight.js into an angular app that uses requirejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, syntax-highlighting

So I'm trying to make a simple little pastebin, this is mostly a tech learning exercise for me. I've got everything working on the frontend except [highlight.js](http://highlightjs.org) (library chosen arbitrarily)

Here's my controller

```
define([
    'highlight',
    'angular',
], function( hl ) {
    'use strict';

    return [      '$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'pastes',
            function ( $scope,   $location,   $routeParams,   pastes ) {
                    console.log( pastes );
                    var digest  = $routeParams.digest;
                    if ( pastes[digest] ) {
                            $scope.code = hl.highlightAuto( pastes[digest] ).value;
                            console.log( $scope.code );
                    }
                    $scope.view = function( view ) {
                            $location.path( view );
                    }
                    $scope.$apply();
            }];
 });
```

and my view

```
 <pre ng-controller="Render"><code class="pre-scrollable">
 {{code}}
 </code></pre>
 <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
    ng-click="view('/')"
 >New Paste</button>
```

to be fair this code works, the problem is that `{{code}}` seems to be sanitizing the html that is being spit out, so I need to find another way to do this. Tried a few other incantations of the library but no progress.

Comment: here's [all my code](https://bitbucket.org/xenoterracide/pastey-frontend/src/9e5ff8b761c9?at=master) in case I've left off a relevant bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is `{{code}}` being sanitized, have you tried [ngBindHtmlUnsafe](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtmlUnsafe)?

```
<pre ng-controller="Render">
    <code class="pre-scrollable" ng-bind-html-unsafe="code"></code>
</pre>
```

Comment: in this case it appears just `ng-bind-html` will work after I loaded `ngSanitize` into my angular module. I did not know about this prior, thanks